# Turn game exe from Microsoft store, into accessible normal exe?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, windows-installer, microsoft-store

The game is Phantom Dust. This is an old game. So I found a app called Reshade. This could potentially add graphic filters to this game giving it a fresh look.

But it won't work unless I can activate the exe by pressing it, so Reshade can access it too.

Currently, I need to use the shortcut that Microsoft made for it, which is in the task bar and start menu.

I found the EXE for the game. I want to change this exe into a normal exe, so I can click it and have it activate the game. Also I want to move the game to my flash drive, so it runs from there.

Image of this games Exe and Message after pressing

[image: Image of this games Exe and Message after pressing]

If I don't click the game shortcut, instead double click the exe itself, this message appears.

So when I drag drop the exe into reshade, it won't work.

Comment: What you want is not possible.  Only the publisher of the game can provide the required executable

Comment: I mean i already have the executable. Its a free game in the app store. 
I'm not going to give up that soon . Every time someone says its not possible. With a little persistence, I found someone with the solution..

Comment: You could forcefully change the ACL for the file, which is the only way to do what you want, but by doing that the application will likely not start.  This is due to the fact the permissions on an application from the Windows Store cannot be changed, if you do change the permissions on say WindowsApps, all UWP applications installed will cease to function

Comment: Yes Bat Man.. "someone" can probably pull this off, however; as @Ramhound points out, Microsoft has gone out of their way to prevent this.  It will probably be no simple hack.  If it was, what is to prevent me from giving the game to someone else?

Comment: Changing the permissions on a single file is actually trivial, but I suspect, once the user running the executable has permissions to the executable it simply won’t work.   By design UWP applications have very limited permissions.

Comment: Welp thanks for the advice. I'll power on and try to google solutions. Currently trying to simply manually move the reshade files into the folder containing the game. 

But it wont give me permission to move. Ive done all the permission app stuff so far nada. 

Thanks regardless.

Comment: I have found this "  ProgramFiles\ModifiableWindowsApp "  This i read in articles maybe for future support for mods for certain games. I guess it dont work now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative answer : Unfortunately this is not possible.

You cannot have your UWP app run as an `.exe`, because
[Universal Windows Platform apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_apps)
run a different Application Model called
[APPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_apps#APPX),
which is fundamentally different than the `exe` application model
and uses a different runtime.

There are ways to wrap an `exe` application in an APPX
(see the
[Desktop App Converter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter)),
but there is no converter/repackager to take you from APPX to `exe`.